# jquery click triggering on unbound element not clicked

Tags: jquery, html

#### HTML

```
<b class="ke">some text <b class="x">x</b></b>
```

#### Javascript

```
function key_tag_click() {
    $('.ke').not('.x').unbind().bind('click', function () {
        console.log('.ke');
        $(this).unbind();
        $(this).children('.x').show();
        x_click();
    });
    return;
}

function x_click() {
    $('.x').unbind().bind('click', function () {
        console.log('.x');
        $(this).unbind();
        $(this).hide();
        key_tag_click();
    });
    return;
}

key_tag_click();
```

1. first I click on .ke

the console logs

**ke**

1. then i click .x

the console logs

**x**

**ke**

Why?? what is triggering .ke click event? at this point .key is unbinded!

Comment: I'm guessing `$('.ke').not('.x')` doesn't do what you think it does, it selects all elements with the class `ke` that does not also have the class `x`, it does not prevent propagation.

Comment: i put .not out shear fustration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on an element, the event is first triggered on that element, then that elements parent, then that elements parent, etc all the way up to the document. That is why clicking on .x results in the click handler for .ke also getting triggered. To prevent it, either return false, stop propagation, or ensure that the click element is the event target.

Option One:

```
$('.x').unbind("click").bind('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
```

Option Two:

```
$('.ke').unbind().bind('click', function (e) {
    if (this !== e.target) return;
    console.log('.ke');
```

Option Three:

```
$('.x').unbind("click").bind('click', function () {
    ... code ...
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is *event bubbling*`. When you click on an element, the click event is also sent to the parent element, its parent, and so on.

Since `x_click()` calls `key_tag_click()` at the end, the event is bound again on `.ke`. After this returns, the event is sent to the `.ke` element, and this handler runs.

To prevent event bubbling, the handler must call `stopPropagation()` or `return false`.

Comment: why bubble in the first place?

Comment: Because nested elements overlap. If you click on an inner element, you're also clicking on all its containers.

Comment: @BenMuircroft Without event bubbling, adding a click event to the button in the last column of every row of a table with 300 rows would mean adding 300 click events rather than one.

Answer (score 0):

code would be something like this-

```
    function key_tag_click() {
        $('.ke').unbind().bind('click', function () {
        console.log('.ke');
        $(this).unbind();
        $(this).children('.x').show();
        x_click();
    });
    return;
    }

    function x_click() {
        $('.x').unbind().bind('click', function () {
        console.log('.x');
        $(this).unbind();
        $(this).hide();
        key_tag_click();
        return false; // return a false to prevent the handler from propagating the
                      //to parent element and thus preventing x from being displayed.
    });
   return ; 
  }

key_tag_click();
```

source: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/